# Use explorer.document as source HtmlDocument for HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, html-agility-pack, mshtml, microsoft.mshtml

I want to use currently loaded webpage in internet explorer as `HtmlDocument` in HtmlAgilityPack. I am using explorer document through mshtml as COM object.

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = explorer.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
```

Then I've tried to convert it to HtmlDocument which is using in HtmlAgilityPack

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hdoc = (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)doc;
```

But it's not working due to invalid cast operation. Exception message is shown below.

[image: Exception Message]

Anyhow I want to use currently loaded webpage as source to htmlagilitypack, I know that I can use HtmlWeb provided by htmlagility pack and load current url but I want to highlight elements which are in the loaded page (elements found using htmlagilitypack) I guess it cannot be done through that kind of implementation. Any ideas to implement this any support will be great. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can't cast between `mshtml.HTMLDocument` and `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`, they're completely distinct classes from different libraries, where one is purely managed and the other is a managed COM wrapper.

What you can do is grab the HTML from the `mshtml.HTMLDocument` and load it into the Agility Pack.

Probably something along these lines:

```
  mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 sourceDoc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3) explorer.Document;  
  string documentContents = sourceDoc.documentElement.outerHTML; 

  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument targetDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

  targetDoc.LoadHtml(documentContents);
```

You could also use the [`IPersistStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690091(v=vs.85).aspx) and then call the Save method, pass a `MemoryStream` and then feed that to the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already done that and achieved what I wanted, but the next step is to add styles for found elements actually in the explorer do you have a suggestion for do that?

Comment: `mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = explorer.Document;
 mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 idoc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)doc;
 String str = idoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
hdoc.LoadHtml(str);` This is the code I have used.

Comment: Updated with your answer. I don't really understand your question, do you update the Agility pack document and then want to see the updates in Explorer?

Comment: In that case `sourceDoc.documentElement.outerElement = targetDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;` will probably work :).

Comment: yeah I done that, but it is consuming lot of time when trying to find elements which are deeper in the hierarchy. I think I'll have to filter elements before doing comparison. Up to now I able to eliminate  elements which are not having same tag name. It improves performance, Any ideas to gain more performance?

Comment: For you misunderstanding, actually I want to confirm that element which is having specific xpath is available (I'm doing that through HtmlAgilityPack) then I want to highlight it in actual web page which is already loaded in explorer.

Comment: Can you post a new question on that? Explain what you want, show what you have, tell what you've tried. That way there is a clear new starting point.